# Google Earth Plugin multilpe placemarks

Tags: google-earth-plugin

I'm using [Google Earth plugin](https://developers.google.com/earth/) in order to show multiple polygons(circles) at the same time, how can I do this?, I have a listbox with lat or `geoDataSplit[0]` and lng or `geoDataSplit[1]`, Want to go through this listbox latlngs, pass them to polygonplacemark, store all the circles may be in an array or what would you suggest and show all of them, the code below prints all the circles but one by one and not all at the same time:

```
var setOfPlacemarks = [];
function createCircle(centerLat, centerLng, radius) {

    function make2Circle(centerLat, centerLng, radius) {

        var ring = ge.createLinearRing('');
        var steps = 25;
        var pi2 = Math.PI * 2;
        for (var i = 0; i < steps; i++) {
            var lat = parseFloat(centerLat) + radius * Math.cos(i / steps * pi2);
            var lng = centerLng + radius * Math.sin(i / steps * pi2);
            ring.getCoordinates().pushLatLngAlt(lat, lng, 0);

        }
        return ring;
    }

    var polygonPlacemark = ge.createPlacemark('');
    polygonPlacemark.setGeometry(ge.createPolygon(''));
    var outer = ge.createLinearRing('');

    var dlist = document.getElementById('salesList');
        for (var i = 0; i < dlist.options.length; i++) {

            var geoData = dlist.options[i].text;
            geoDataSplit = geoData.split(",");
            polygonPlacemark.getGeometry().setOuterBoundary(make2Circle(parseFloat(geoDataSplit[0]), parseFloat(geoDataSplit[1]), .00001*parseInt(geoDataSplit[2])/5));
            polygonPlacemark.setName(geoDataSplit[2]);

            ge.getFeatures().appendChild(polygonPlacemark);
            setOfPlacemarks.push(polygonPlacemark);
        }
        printAllPlacemarks();
}

function printAllPlacemarks() {

    var kmlObjectList = ge.getFeatures().getChildNodes();
    alert(kmlObjectList);
    for (var i = 0; i < setOfPlacemarks.length; i++) {
        alert(setOfPlacemarks[i]);
        ge.getFeatures().appendChild(setOfPlacemarks[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: It isn't really clear what you are asking. What do you mean by "prints all the circles" - are you talking about displaying the geometry in the plugin or something else? Happy to help if you can explain a bit better.